# Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete BlockStatements cant fix

Tags: java

i am trying to make a encryption program.

How do i get rid of "Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete BlockStatements" on line 100

```
<imports>

public class Afp {

...

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    ....

    JButton btnEncrypt = new JButton("Encrypt");
    btnEncrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                String text;
                StringBuffer passWord = new StringBuffer(""+ text);

            for(int i = 0; i < passWord.length(); i++){
                int temp = 0;
                temp = (int)passWord.charAt(i);
                temp = temp*9834 / 8942 /33 *90023243 * 9 +124324534 - 2335 *24324;
                passWord.setCharAt(i, (char)temp);
            }   
            }


        }
    });
    ...
}
}
```

Comment: `try` block requires `catch` or/and `finally`.

Comment: I have deleted your second question to save the entire Question from being closed as "too broad".   Please ask separate (i.e. unrelated) questions as distinct Questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting Syntax Error because you have written try block without catch or finally block. You can either delete try block or Add catch or finally

Answer (score 5):

The possible syntaxes for a `try` statement go something like this:

```
// 1 try-catch

    try {
       ....
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
       ...
    }

// 2 try-catch-finally

    try {
       ....
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
       ...
    } finally {
       ...
    }

// 3 try-finally

    try {
       ....
    } finally {
       ...
    }

// 4 try with resources

    try (...) {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

(In forms 1, 2 and 3, you have to have *at least* one `catch` or a `finally` ... or both.  In the 4th form, you can leave out both `catch` and `finally` blocks because there is an implicit final block.)

Your code doesn't match any of these.  However, the correct fix for your code depends on what you are trying to do with that `try` statement.  If you don't know, then perhaps just delete `try {` and the matching `}`.